# I am trying to create a GUI that will open a new label with different color whenever the next button is clicked

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Welcome 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 700, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        JButton btn = new JButton("next");
        btn.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 100);
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
        JLabel label3 = new JLabel();
        //first label 
        label1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        label1.add(btn);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label1);
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.getContentPane().remove(label1);
                frame.getContentPane().repaint();
                frame.getContentPane().revalidate();
                frame.getContentPane().add(label2);
            }
        });
        //second 
        JLabel label2.setBackground(Color.RED);
        JButton btn2 = new JButton("next");
        btn2.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 100);
        label2.add(btn2);
        btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.getContentPane().remove(label1);
                frame.getContentPane().repaint();
                frame.getContentPane().revalidate();
                frame.getContentPane().add(label3);
            }
        });
        //third JLabel 
        label3.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe your question more clearly.

Comment: @Kaveh is right.  Here is some guidance:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `frame.setVisible(true);`  should be done last.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use setBounds().Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.
2. Changing the background of a label doesn't do anything. By default a JLabel is transparent so the background is not painted. To see the background you first need to use `label.setOpaque(true);`
3. Don't use remove/add logic. To swap a component in the same position in the frame use a `CardLayout`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Start with the working code and then make changes. The code in the tutorial is better structured than your current code and demonstrates how to use the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. All Swing components should be created and modified on the EDT.